# Cannot resolve symbol union

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, azure-databricks

I am using below function to list the directories. It works in Azure databricks but when I am adding in IntelliJ project code, it is not able to resolve "union" keyword. Do I need import anything here?

```
def listLeafDirectories(path: String): Array[String] =
  dbutils.fs.ls(path).map(file => {
    // Work around double encoding bug
    val path = file.path.replace("%25", "%").replace("%25", "%")
    if (file.isDir) listLeafDirectories(path)
    else Array[String](path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf("/")+1))
  }).reduceOption(_ union _).getOrElse(Array()).distinct
```

[image]

**ADB Notebook successful execution:**

[image]

Comment: I think this might be happening since `union` returns an `ArraySeq[String]` in your case and reduceOption expects `f: (Array[String], Array[String]) => Array[String])`, so it doesn't fit in there.

Comment: Same function executes fine in ADB notebook. So I think the code is correct.

Comment: Does the code run? If not, what is the compiler error (rather than the IntelliJ error)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake.

In the screenshot provided highlighting error, I have recurse flag which I was not passing to the function (in same function).

So below one worked:

```
  def listDirectories(dir: String, recurse: Boolean): Array[String] = {
    dbutils.fs.ls(dir).map(file => {
      val path = file.path.replace("%25", "%").replace("%25", "%")
      if (file.isDir) listDirectories(path,recurse)
      else Array[String](path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")+1))
    }).reduceOption(_ union _).getOrElse(Array()).distinct
  }
```